# custom cookie session persistance

Tags: session, cookies, weblogic, persistence

In weblogic, as I have requirement of custom cookie name for session management, I used the following in my weblogic.xml

```
<session-descriptor>
    <timeout-secs>7200</timeout-secs>
    <cookies-enabled>true</cookies-enabled>
    <persistent-store-type>cookie</persistent-store-type>
    <persistent-store-cookie-name>MY_PARAM</persistent-store-cookie-name>
</session-descriptor>
```

Got following error at the statement that puts a number into session...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie based sessions support 
    attributes of
    type "String" only; could not set attribute: CUSTID
             at 
    weblogic.servlet.internal.session.CookieSessionData.setAttribute(Cook
    ieSessionData.java:63)
```

This was working fine earlier to using custom cookie name for persistence. Am I missing something? What can I do to avoid code changes arising out of custom cookie name requirement
**UPDATE:**

myCustId is a number and I am trying to put it in CUSTID session attributr:

```
session.setAttribute("CUSTID", myCustId);
```

So, after the above error, if I change the code like the below, problem is solved.

```
session.setAttribute("CUSTID", myCustId.toString());
```

But I dont want to make these changes as many other such numeric fields are set as session attributes.

Comment: What does your code look like that is setting the attribute?

Comment: Please see my question updated

Answer (score 0):

When you switched over to the custom cookie, WebLogic started using a different class to manage sessions. Unfortunately for you this class has the String check on the setAttribute method as noted in the documentation here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webapp/sessions.html#wp139726

"You can store only string attributes in the session. If you store any other type of object in the session, an IllegalArgument exception is thrown."